# How to download excel file using Ajax method- here my file is downloaded in Temp folder not Downloaded in Browser?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I want to download an excel file. I'm using ajax method to get the file but it's not working for me. My file is downloaded into a temp folder but it's not downloading in the browser.

c# and jquery

**jquery**

```
//Exporting errors to excel file
function ExcportErrorListToExcel() {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Import/ExportErrorToExcel',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { dataExchangeSelectedColum: $('#hdnSelectedColumn').val(), entityvalue: $('#hdnEntity').val(), filename: $('#hdnFileName').val() },       
        //contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        success: function (returnValue) {
            debugger;       
            window.location = '/Import/ExportErrorToExcel?file=' + returnValue.filename;
            //alert('success');
        }
    });
}
```

**controller**

```
#region ExportErrorToExcel        
        public ActionResult ExportErrorToExcel(string dataExchangeSelectedColum, string entityvalue, string filename)
        {
            UA patsUA = Session["PaTSUA"] as UA;
            DataTable dataTable = null;
            dataTable = _dataExchangeBusiness.DataValidation(dataExchangeSelectedColum, entityvalue, filename, patsUA.DBConnectionString);

            string tempPath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx");


          _dataExchangeBusiness.ExportErrorToExcel(dataTable,tempPath, entityvalue);

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(tempPath);
            if (fileInfo.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                byte[] excelBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempPath);

                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(excelBytes);
                Response.ContentType= "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ErrorList.xlsx");
                Response.Buffer = true;
                memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
                //System.IO.File.Delete(tempPath);
            }

            //var errorRowList = (from e in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            //                             where e.Field<string>("DataError").ToString() != ""
            //                             select e).ToList();

            return File(tempPath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", Path.GetFileName(tempPath));
            //return Json(new { Status = "OK", Records = tempPath, contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
        }
        #endregion ExportErrorToExcel
```

Comment: Don’t use Ajax, just redirect the user to the controller location like you’re doing in the `success` function. The browser will force a download based on the response headers.

Comment: @StaticBeagle but here im passing some values to that controller

Comment: @StaticBeagle in this my file is actually downloaded into  a temp file but its not downloded in browser

Comment: can you share your folder structure

Comment: @UdaraKasun Structre means?

Comment: temp file location

Comment: its in Userinterface. of my project folder. Im using C# MVC

Comment: ok. why you try to rederect using  "/Import/ExportErrorToExcel" this?

Comment: @UdaraKasun To get the file name. for downloading. it in browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186994/discussion-between-udara-kasun-and-dhanil-dinesan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
//Exporting errors to excel file
function ExcportErrorListToExcel() {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Import/ExportErrorToExcel',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { dataExchangeSelectedColum: $('#hdnSelectedColumn').val(), entityvalue: $('#hdnEntity').val(), filename: $('#hdnFileName').val() },       
        //contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        success: function (returnValue) {
            debugger;  
            var link=document.createElement('a');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.href="/Temp/" + returnValue.filename;
            link.click();
            link.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Let me try with this one. I will update the result here

Comment: stille i didnt get the result. I didnt get the file name from controller to this ajax why this is happen?

Comment: send me folder structure

Comment: "D:\\Dhanils_Kingdom\\Dhanil\\Projects\\PATS\\PATS.UserInterface\\Temp\\61c62b82-eab5-40bf-8c35-4653ff05644b.xlsx"
this is the path where my excel file now downloaded

Comment: your project name may be ''PATS"

Comment: Yes it the project name

Comment: temp folder inside the  PATS.UserInterface folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187024/discussion-between-dhanil-dinesan-and-udara-kasun).

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply done by split that controller function into two.The first function will
save the file in a temp folder and pass the file name to the jquery Ajax function and in its success section it will redirected to the second function in the controller.Here we will Download the file

Here is the Ajax

```
    function ExportErrorListToExcel() {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: "Import/ExportErrorToExcel",
        type: "POST",
        data: { dataExchangeSelectedColum: $('#hdnSelectedColumn').val(), entityvalue: $('#hdnEntity').val(), filename: $('#hdnFileName').val() },       
        success: function (responsetext, status, xhr) {
            debugger;
            window.location = 'Import/DownloadErrorData?fname=' + responsetext.FileName;
        }
    });
   // $('#ExcelExportForm').submit();
}
```

Here is the Controller function where the file is saved into a temp folder

```
#region ExportErrorToExcel
    //This function will return the file name to script
    public ActionResult ExportErrorToExcel(string dataExchangeSelectedColum, string entityvalue, string filename)
    {

        UA patsUA = Session["PaTSUA"] as UA;
        DataTable dataTable = null;
        dataTable = _dataExchangeBusiness.DataValidation(dataExchangeSelectedColum, entityvalue, filename, patsUA.DBConnectionString);

        string tempPath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+ ".xlsx");            

        _dataExchangeBusiness.ExportErrorToExcel(dataTable,tempPath, entityvalue);
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(tempPath);

        return Json(new { Result = "true", Message = "Success", FileName = fname,Entity=entityvalue });
    }
    #endregion ExportErrorToExcel
```

Here is the controller 2nd function for download the file from **Temp** folder

```
#region DownloadErrorData

    //In this function recieve the filename and will download it from the location
    public ActionResult DownloadErrorData(string fname)
    {
        string fileName ="ErrorList.xlsx";
        string filePath= Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/" + fname));
        try
        {
            string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
            foreach (string file in allFiles)
            {
                FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(file);
                if (fileinfo.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2))
                {
                    fileinfo.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";//web content type of .xlsx files
        return File(filePath, contentType, fileName);
    }
    #endregion DownloadErrorData
```

Hope this will help for someone :)

Comment: This works for me locally, but on actual server it breaks, probably due to write/delete restrictions. There has to be a better way..